# "How to calculate difference in succesive time values in Python"

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime

I'am trying to calculate the difference between string time values but i could not read microseconds format. Why i have this type of errors ? and how i can fix my code for it ?

I have already tried "datetime.strptime" method to get string to time format then use pandas.dataframe.diff method to calculate the difference between each item in the list and create a column in excel for it.

````
```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd 

for itemz in time_list:
    df = pd.DataFrame(datetime.strptime(itemz, '%H %M %S %f'))
    ls_cnv.append(df.diff())

df = pd.DataFrame(time_list)
ls_cnv = [df.diff()]

print (ls_cnv)

```
````

I expect the output to be

```
ls_cnv = [NaN, 00:00:00, 00:00:00] 
time_list = ['10:54:05.912783', '10:54:05.912783', '10:54:05.912783']
```

but i have instead (time data '10:54:05.906224' does not match format '%H %M %S %f')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get is because you are using `strptime` wrong.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(datetime.strptime(itemz, '%H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

The above would be the correct form, the one passed from your `time_list` but that's not the case. You create the `DataFrame` in the wrong way too. `DataFrame` is a table if you wish of data. The following lines will create and replace in every loop a new `DataFrame` for every `itemz` which is one element of your list at time. So it will create a `DataFrame` with one element in the first loop which will be `'10:54:05.912783'` and it will `diff()` that with itself while there is no other value.

```
for itemz in time_list:
    df = pd.DataFrame(datetime.strptime(itemz, '%H %M %S %f'))
    ls_cnv.append(df.diff())
```

Maybe what you wanted to do is the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

ls_cnv = []
time_list = ['10:54:03.912743', '10:54:05.912783', '10:44:05.912783']

df = pd.to_datetime(time_list)
data = pd.DataFrame({'index': range(len(time_list))}, index=df)
a = pd.Series(data.index).diff()
ls_cnv.append(a)
print (ls_cnv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because your time format must include colons and point like this

```
"%H:%M:%S.%f"
```

Comment: I did not understand your answer very well @jpaul. Could you explain more in details ?

Comment: I mean you should write strptime(itemz, '%H:%M:%S.%f') with colons and point instead of strptime(itemz, '%H %M %S %f') with spaces.